# CSS Transition/Transform not working well in Safari desktop and iOS

Tags: css, safari, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm having a strange issue with transitions and transforms in Safari in the sub-900px media query in desktop and iOS. They mostly work well, with the exception of the a.logo element on this site:

http://eclipseinterface.com/#welcome

It feels like the transition happens with all of the other elements, but the transform property just pops into place when the transition ends.

I've tried advice on SO that wants me to vendor prefix the translate parameter as well, but that seems to make no difference.

Any thoughts? I've been picking at this bug for a few hours now :(

Comment: Please reproduce your issue using a [mcve]. After it will be fixed, the link above will serve absolutely no purpose to anyone trying to debug a similar issue, because the issue in your page would have been fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I will be sure to do that once I have identified the problem and can isolate it.